# Golf mk3 front suspension mount protrudes from turret

Tags: suspension, golf, struts

Tried googling this but couldn't find the answer, so here goes..

As said above - top bit of the strut mounting is protruding from the turret. If i jack the car up it drops to rest on the turret again. I don't think it's always been like this but maybe it has and I never noticed!

[image: As shown here:]

So.. is this normal or has something broken? Both the front mounts are doing the same thing which makes me hopeful that i just never noticed before but wanted to be sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Upper Strut mounts can wear out, They have to allow some travel, but it will get excessive as they wear out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal.  I currently have two Mk3 Golf (plus a Mk1 and a Mk6) and have previously owned a number of other Mk3's, both Cabriolet and Hatchback.  They all look like this.

Comment: It's awesome when hands-on knowledge comes to SE! :o)

Comment: It looks as if the rubber seal has a groove which is supposed to clip into the top of the turret, but in the picture the turret is a bit corroded and it has probably popped out some time when you drove over a bump. The metal part is supposed to move up and down, as the answer says.

Comment: The rubber seal bit is just wrapped around the top of the top mount and doesn’t attach to the turret.